# How to pass a php value with AJAX GET

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I would like to send a php value with this function

```
$k = $_GET['k'];

function getData() {
    $.post('page.php', {
    action  : 'loader',
    number : $settings.nop,
    offset : offset,

    //I LIKE TO SEND $k
}
```

Comment: Same way you always pass parameters when using GET: appending variables in te query string. `$.post('page.php?k=something', ...` (or did I get the qestion wrong?)

Comment: you can pass the php variable at the getData function, then use it in your js

Comment: Your title would suggest the use of POST. In you code I think you looking for GET.

Comment: @JohannesH. i tryed page.php?k=1 but empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PHP is a server side language** and **JS is a client side language** So this variable is not directly accessible in javascript which can be sent in an ajax request.

So from php side you can expose this variable `$k` using a global variable and then send it in the ajax call from Js like this

#### PHP

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.myGlobalVariable = "<?php echo $_GET['k'] ?>"
</script>
```

Now you can send it in JS like this.

#### JS

```
function getData() {
    $.post('page.php', {
    action  : 'loader',
    number : $settings.nop,
    offset : offset,
    variable : myGlobalVariable //Value of myGlobalVariable will be set by PHP code
}
```

Comment: long time didn't touch PHP but isn't it: `"<?php echo $_GET['k']; ?>"`

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks man!! I really don't remember much PHP syntax..I am not a PHP guy but I knew some good soul will correct me. Thanks a lot

Comment: @blunderboy You saved me man, i would +9999 but i don't have enouth reputation, thanks BLUNDER BOY :)

Comment: @user3281766 Everybody feels the same way when his problem gets solved. Important thing is you understand the problem and understand how it is solved. I am glad I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getData(k) {
       return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "page.php",
            data: {k : k}, 
            cache: false,

            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
}
```

In PHP file:

```
$k = $_POST['k'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to echo `$_GET['k'];` using PHP. For security reasons ensure you use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode).

```
function getData() {
    $.post('page.php', {
    action  : 'loader',
    number : $settings.nop,
    offset : offset,
    k: <?php echo json_encode($_GET['k']); ?>
}
```